# Audio play on navigation and button press

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

the issue I'm having is that my application is supposed to play an audio clip on a button press. However, I'm navigating using a button from a previous screen to this one. Upon arrival all of the audio files play. Is there a way to stop this? Regardless of where I put pTest and pTest2, they always play upon navigation. Is there My code is below:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Typography, Grid } from "@material-ui/core"
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { MemoryRouter as Router } from 'react-router';
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom';




const useStyles = makeStyles({
  helloThereStyle:{
    fontStyle: 'oblique',
    color: "blue",
    fontSize: '30px'
  },
  buttonStyles: {
    color: 'blue',

  }
});
  const click = () =>{
    console.log("click")
  }

  let aTest = new Audio("/Assets/Sound/test.wav")

  const pTest = () => {
    aTest.play()
  }
  let aTest2 = new Audio("/Assets/Sound/test2.wav")

  const pTest2 = () => {
    aTest2.play()
  }

function Two() {
  
  const classes = useStyles();


  return (
    <div className="Two">
      <h1>Page Two</h1>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid xs={1}>
          <Button 
          className={classes.buttonStyles} 
          variant="outlined" 
          color="primary"
          startIcon={<Avatar src={'/Assets/back.png'}/>}
          component={RouterLink} 
          to="/"
          >
          </Button>
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs={1}>
          <Button 
          className={classes.buttonStyles} 
          variant="outlined" 
          color="primary"
          startIcon={<Avatar src={'https://i.redd.it/w3kr4m2fi3111.png'} />}
          component={RouterLink} 
          to="/Two"
          onClick={pTest()}
          >Test
          </Button>
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs={1}>
          <Button 
          className={classes.buttonStyles} 
          variant="outlined" 
          color="primary"
          startIcon={<Avatar src={'https://i.redd.it/w3kr4m2fi3111.png'} />}
          component={RouterLink} 
          to="/Two"
          onClick={pTest2()}
          >Test2
          </Button>
        </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </div>

  );
}

export default Two;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions in your `onclick` run without any click event needed, so you need to change that

```
onClick = {() => pTest2()}
```

and

```
onClick={ () => pTest()}
```